# How to switch between different workbooks to copy/paste information

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This is my first attempt at writing a macro at work, so please go easy on me if this is really simple, I couldn't find a solution online and kept getting errors in my code:

Basically, I have a Raw Data file and I want to copy different filtered data into a new workbook. I already pass the part where I copy column M into a new created workbook but I don't know how to make the code go back to the Raw Data file and copy another column, then paste it into another column in the same new workbook.

Here's what I have so far, the lines with ''' are what I tried and got errors for. Not sure why it's not working

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim SourceFile As String

Sub Reconcile()

FilePath = Sheets("Reconcile").Range("E5")     'location of saved attachment
If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

SourceFile = Sheets("Reconcile").Range("E7") 'name of attachment file

FilePath = FilePath & SourceFile

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath, UpdateLinks:=False 'open sourcefile     workbook
ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

'''Set DataFile = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name) 'activeworkbook is the raw data file

'Copy the date column into a new wb and remove duplicates
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$1666").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Rows(1).Delete

'''DataFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

The last line is just me trying to go back to the raw data file and selecting cell A1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by creating a Worksheet object and a couple of Workbook objects

```
Dim wsReconcile As Worksheet
Dim wbDatafile As Workbook
Dim wbNewfile As Workbook
```

Then, at the start of your code, before you open any new workbooks set wsReconcile to your Reconcile sheet

```
Set wsReconcile = Worksheets("Reconcile")
```

Then, when you do your WorkBooks.Open of your datafile, you can assign it to the wbDatafile object

```
Set wbDatafile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath, UpdateLinks:=False) 'open sourcefile     workbook
```

And, when you add your new workbook, assign it to the wbNewfile object

```
Set wbNewfile = Workbooks.Add
```

Then, every time you need to refer to the data file, use the wbDatafile object, e.g.

```
wbDatafile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
```

Every time you need to refer to the new file, use the wbNewfile object, e.g.

```
wbNewfile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$A$1666").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
wbNewfile.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Delete
```

And, when you want to refer to the original Reconcile sheet, you can use the wsReconcile object, e.g.

```
SourceFile = wsReconcile.Range("E7")
```

Comment: "Set wbDatafile = Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath, UpdateLinks:=False 'open sourcefile    " this line didn't work for me but I got the same result using "Set wbDatafile = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)"

Thanks so much for explaining your steps so clearly! I really appreciate it

Comment: @S.Kat - That's a typo - I forgot to put brackets around the parameters.  I'll edit the answer so no-one else gets confused.

Comment: @S.Kat P.S. `Set wbDatafile = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)` would be equivalent to `Set wbDatafile = ActiveWorkbook`